# Lightning pageReference() returns null

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, forcenavigatetourl

I have two components OP_Target and OP_Source. I want to navigate to Target from Source. I have implemented lightning:isUrlAddressable in target and trying to get it's url in source.
EDIT:- I have added `<aura:attribute name="pageReference" type="Object"/>
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>` in source component as well.

Source's Code :-

```
var type = component.get('v.item.Type__c');
var wList = component.get('v.item.wslrList');
var pageReference = {
        type: 'standard__component',
        attributes: {
            componentName: "c__OP_Target",
        },
        state: {
            "c__Type": type,
            "c__wList" : wList
        }
    };
component.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);

    var navService = component.find("navService");
    var pageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");//THIS COMES NULL
    event.preventDefault();
    navService.navigate(pageRef);

    var url=navService.generateUrl(pageRef);
    event.preventDefault();
    var defaultUrl = "www.something.com";
    navService.generateUrl(pageReference)
        .then($A.getCallback(function(url) {
            component.set("v.url", url ? url : defaultUrl);
        }), $A.getCallback(function(error) {
            component.set("v.url", defaultUrl);
        }));
console.log('url->',component.get("v.url"));
```

The pageReference comes null. I have removed flexipage implementations as per the
document [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:hasPageReference/documentation).). Appreciate any views.
Do I need to add something else in target other than isUrlAddressable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add navigation service to your component xml?

```
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
```

Comment: Apologies , I have edited the question. and yes i have added <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/> in source component.